# Screen almost black when external monitor is disconnected

Tags: kubuntu, laptop, lenovo, external-monitor

To a laptop (Lenovo Ideapad) with the latest kubuntu installed an external monitor is connected, it is recognised automatically and works fine with split-screen mode (with the laptop screen set as primary).

However, after the monitor is disconnected the laptop screen turns black. After restarting the laptop, only a small part on the left side of the laptop screen is visible, the rest (about 95 %) of the screen stays black and it's not possible to do anything (especially to open the preferences).

Once the external monitor is connected to the laptop again, both screens show up fine.

So, what do I have to do in order to be able to use the laptop without external monitor again?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the contents of `~/.local/share/kscreen/` before shutting down with external monitor connected worked.

(s. https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=128190)

Comment: This tip is useful even if the external monitor got configured totally badly, and there is no access to KDE GUI (but tty1 or ssh works).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after doing upgrates with the external monitor plugged in.

delete the monitor profile and reboot without external plugged in.

multiple monitors configuration is saved in ~/.config/monitors.xml.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the monitor profile in the preference window? It's not my laptop and neither me nor the owner are familiar with linux...

Comment: no you have to do it from the file manager show hidden files in your home directory to see the config folder

Answer (score 0):

Do not delete any files, instead go-to settings/display and turn off the monitor before disconnecting it.